# How to compress an image with Gimp?

Tags: gimp, compression

I took a picture with my phone device and it is a **jpg** image that weighs about 8 MB.

I believe that compressing it will greatly reduce the file size.

I can't compress it in tinyPNG because it's more than 5 MB but I was able to compress it with iloveimg.com and reduce file size from 8 MB to about 1.2 MB.

Anyway, I would still like to ask how to compress an image with Gimp?

Comment: When you export as a JPEG from GIMP, you can adjust the compression settings using the quality slider. Less quality = more compression.  There's no point exporting a JPEG as a PNG in GIMP. You will get a larger file size,, not smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Compressing an photo is a matter of compromise. **You will always lose data** and the compressed photo **will never be as good as the original**. Your only choice is what kind of data (or combination thereof) you shed:

- You can reduce the colors. This is what is done by many PNG "compressors", the ultimate step being the color-indexed images (with only 256 colors in the image, every pixel can be encoded on one byte). This is best avoided for photography.
- You can reduce the pixels by scaling/cropping the image. If your 12MPix (4000×3000) image is 8MB, and you make it twice as small (2000×1500), you have divided the pixel count by 4 and with the same compression technique and parameters your file is 4 times smaller. This typically what happens when you "share" the image from your phone, the sharing apps make a smaller a version of the image.
- You can reduce the definition in several more complex ways (a little bit of everything....), which is what is done in JPEG compression.

With Gimp:

- Depending on intended usage, the first thing to do is to scale the image to a reasonable size. I cannot give hard numbers but something that fits a HD TV image is 1920×1080 (3830×2160 for 4K). This is done with `Image > Scale image`:

[image]

You can then export to file. Use `File > Export as`, pick a directory, and *change the name to avoid overwriting your original image*:

[image]

You then get this dialog:

[image]

And after clicking these two:

- Gimp displays a preview of the image as it will be saved
- The options dialog becomes this:

[image]

Your main option is the `Quality` slider, but the `Subsampling` option is often overlooked. The dialog shows you in real-time the size of the resulting file, while the preview is updated to show the resulting image, so you can check how far you can go quality-wise.

Comment: Your comments on the start of the answer about types of compression and data loss are very important - I suggest also adding a suggestion to make a backup of the original image before compressing it with tool whatsoever. Gimp copies-changes-pastes it in a different file ("exports") yes but not necessarily any program will do that, hence I think adding a note about backups is so important.

Comment: Backups are always useful even if you don't compress. Added a suggestion to change the name in the export dialog to avoid overwriting the source.